# CRM 2011: How to update MessageProcessorMinimumInactiveSeconds field in DeploymentProperties table?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, workflow-foundation

Is there any supported way to update value for field **MessageProcessorMinimumInactiveSeconds** in  **DeploymentProperties** table in MSCRM_CONFIG database?

I have a worklfow that should be executed every **10 minutes**. And there is known problem with *infinite loop*. I created scheduled WF same way [like this](http://crmbusiness.wordpress.com/2011/05/24/crm-2011-how-to-schedule-recurring-workflows-in-crm-2011/). Also, is there any other solution for scheduled workflows in crm?

Answer (score 0):

I have several suggestions how to make recurrent actions in CRM without touching DB.

1. You can create on-demand workflow and trigger it using external application or SSIS package.
2. You can create external windows service that will do all required actions instead of CRM.
3. You can use SSIS packages.